# How to sum up the value from text boxes?

Tags: c#

I have 6 text boxes in Visual Studio code 2019. I want to make it so when I put numbers in to the textbox a separate textbox displays the sum of the other 6 textboxes. How can I make such a thing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, firstly you would want to name your textboxes if you haven't. You will also want to add a button that will start calculating.

Add a `Name = "textBoxName"` to each of your texbox.
For example...

1st Textbox = `Name = "textBox1"`

2nd Textbox = `Name = "textBox2"`

and etc...

We also need to add a textbox for the result, for this example we will name it.. "`Name = "resultTextBox"`".

Then add a button with a on_click event. "`Click="CalcBtn_Click"`"
So whenever you click you this button the on_click event will trigger.
Then in your C# code behind just add this...

**C# (Code Behind)**

```cs
        private void CalcBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Convert all the textbox numbers to integers.
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox1);
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox2);
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox3);
            int num4 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox4);
            int num5 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox5);
            int num6 = Convert.ToInt16(textbox6);
            // Now we add all them up. 
            int result = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6;
            // Now we change the text of the result textbox to the result.
            resultTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
        }
```

This is just a simple way of doing it, you can do the design and any adjustments by yourself.